# import 'module' as mod not working

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I have a simple import statement:

```
import './dataMapper' as dataMap;
```

I am getting an error

Module build failed: SyntaxError: data.jsx: Unexpected token (1:22)

I can't seem to figure out why. If I just plain import without "as ...", it works.

According to at least this:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/

it is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the correct syntax <s>(and it's not on the page you linked either)</s>. You'll want to have a look at http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html for a good reference.

Your code should be

```
import dataMap from './dataMapper'; // to import the default
```

or

```
import * as dataMap from './dataMapper'; // to import the module object
```

Comment: This is separate, I know this syntax. I am not talking about importing a particular exported value, but the entire module and then accessing exported values as properties. It is there on the linked page. Ctrl+F this to find it "You can also import the entire module as an object" (sans quotes)

Comment: Are you looking for `import * as dataMap from './dataMapper';`?

Comment: @SiamJi: Oh, I must have skipped that. `import 'utility' as utils;` is rubbish.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I guess that's the correct syntax then!

Comment: @SiamJi: That's what I'm saying, yes.